# Configuring Apache for dynamic folders

Tags: php, regex, apache, symfony

**Objective :**

I am using Gitlab to deploy dynamic environments of a Symfony3 website on an Apache server, and I am trying to configure the website to redirect to the correct sub-folder and still apply the route.

The URL is of this form : https://sub.domain.com/review-15-connexi-d7rgbx/ ("15-connexi-d7rgbx" is the dynamic part).

I try to make this URL to work : https://sub.domain.com/review-15-connexi-d7rgbx/path-to-route

Here is the `AliasMatch` directive in the `sub.domain.com.conf` file that works fine :

```
AliasMatch "^/review-([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)(.*)" "/var/www/REVIEW/review-$1/web$2"
```

And here is the `DirectoryMatch` directive that partially work (cf. Problem) :

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/REVIEW/review-([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/web">
    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
</DirectoryMatch>
```

**Problem :**

When I go to https://sub.domain.com/review-15-connexi-d7rgbx/, Symfony detects the need to be authenticated and redirect to https://sub.domain.com/review-15-connexi-d7rgbx/login but this URL returns a 404 error.

When I replace the `DirectoryMatch` directive with the following one, both the URL work :

```
<Directory "/var/www/REVIEW/review-15-connexi-d7rgbx/web">
    ...
</Directory>
```

Why doesn't the `DirectoryMatch` directive work ?